# Pandas fillna to empty dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a 'metadata' column that should contain a dictionary as value. However, some values are missing and set to NaN. I would like this to be {} instead.
Sometimes, the entire column is missing and initializing it to {} is also problematic.

For adding the column

```
tspd['metadata'] = {} # fails
tspd['metadata'] = [{} for _ in tspd.index] # works
```

For filling missing values

```
tspd['metadata'].replace(np.nan,{}) # does nothing
tspd['metadata'].fillna({})  # likewise does nothing
tspd.loc[tspd['metadata'].isna(), 'metadata'] = {} # error
tspd['metadata'] = tspd['metadata'].where(~tspd['metadata'].isna(), other={}) # this sets the NaN values to <built-in method values of dict object>
```

So adding the column works, but is a bit ugly. Replacing the values without some (slow) loop seems not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`, so for replace missing values is possible use:

```
tspd = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2], 'metadata':[{'a':'s'}, np.nan, {'d':'e'}]})

tspd['metadata'] = tspd['metadata'].apply(lambda x: {} if x != x else x)
print(tspd)

   a    metadata
0  0  {'a': 's'}
1  1          {}
2  2  {'d': 'e'}
```

Or:

```
tspd['metadata'] = [{} if x != x else x for x in tspd['metadata']]
```

Comment: This usually causes the reference to `{}` to be copied `len(tspd)` times, so a modification made to it will be copied to all rows. It might be better to use `[{} for i in range len(tspd)]`

Comment: Thanks, the apply trick works
tspd['metadata'] = tspd['metadata'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,dict) else {}) 
is what I used in the end

Answer (score 2):

Do not using `[{}] * len(tspd)`

```
tspd['metadata'] = [{}for x in range(len(tspd))]
tspd
Out[326]: 
   a metadata
0  0       {}
1  1       {}
2  2       {}
```

---

Detail

```
tspd['metadata'] = [{}] * len(tspd)
tspd['metadata'].iloc[0]['lll']=1
tspd # see all duplicated here ,since they are the same copy 
Out[324]: 
   a    metadata
0  0  {'lll': 1}
1  1  {'lll': 1}
2  2  {'lll': 1}
```

---

Do it one by one , each time create the iid `{}`

```
tspd['metadata'] = [{}for x in range(len(tspd))]
tspd
Out[326]: 
   a metadata
0  0       {}
1  1       {}
2  2       {}
tspd['metadata'].iloc[0]['lll']=1
tspd
Out[328]: 
   a    metadata
0  0  {'lll': 1}
1  1          {}
2  2          {}
```